# Is there a Javascript variable that represents local scope? Like global?

Tags: javascript, node.js

`global` is an object containing any global variables (at least in Node.js, they're in `window` in the browser).

Is there a similar variable that represents the current scope? Local variables don't show up in `global` (for a good reason :) )

```
asdf = "hello";
var local = "hello";

console.log(global); // includes asdf
console.log(???);    // includes local?
```

Comment: Is this for debugging? I can't imagine any real-world scenario where this would be useful...

Comment: I really don't want to sound negative, but I can't help but disliking the attitude "cant' imagine why you would want to do X". Where do you guys think innovation comes from? For example, what could prime number EVER be useful for? How could anyone ever need more than 64KB of RAM? Etc..

Comment: I even made up an example. Lets say we have a function for swapping the values of two properties in an object, like this: var swap = function(target, a, b) { var temp = target[a]; target[a] = target[b]; target[b] = temp; }

Comment: Then I could do the following, if there was an object called "locals" representing the local scope: var x = 5; var y = 10; swap(locals, "x", "y");

Comment: But with the current limits of javascript, it's impossible to swap two local variables with each other. Even if things seems useless at first glance, there is always someone that can think of a useful scenario. "Useless" things are fantastic!

Comment: @Jakob: If there were such a variable "locals", it would mean you can pass that variable around which destroys the meaning of "local".

Comment: It's for a framework. I want to do something fancy with proxies, and the fw would be a lot cooler if I could say "anything you access within this (synchronous) function call is a proxy". It's probably good that such an object doesn't exist, to prevent atrocities, but I promise to be responsible if the V8 gods want to expose that object in node/v8 :)

Comment: @pimvdb ha, did you edit my smiley-paren? Is that the standard now? I remember the xkcd comic about that.

Comment: @Sean Clark Hess: I was just doing some minor fixes. I now see the comic there... If you want you can change it back :)

Comment: Exactly. Everything is about being responsible. Dynamic typing is dangerous too. Being able to change methods of any class at any time is dangerous as well. Some languages decides to protect the programmer from themselves (which is fine), but some languages decides to do the opposite: freedom/power/responsibility. It's not "bad". It's just different.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Is there an object represents the local scope?

Yes. There is.

### Could you access the object (directly)?

No. You can't.

Why?
JavaScript has only function scope - which is the **execution Context**. Within the **execution Context**, an **Activation object**(also known as `call object`) is used to create local variables as its property. However,

> ...it is not a normal object as it has no prototype (at least not a defined prototype) and it cannot be directly referenced by javascript code.

[Reference](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/#clExCon)

Comment: As many things in the specification, this object may be completely virtual, if the implementation chooses so. The main points is, it can not be used in the code.

Comment: @herby Yeah, it is. This is an **abstract** object in the specification.

Comment: Just as a side note, there are similar languages, for example Io (which is object-oriented, has prototypes, first-class functions etc) where you can access that object. Even if such unknown languages rarely are used for "real" projects, experimenting with them is useful as it teaches us how things *could* work (or actually work, behind the scenes).