# How to list scope variables in node debugger

Tags: node.js, debugging

I was wondering if there was a way to list all scope variables (and possibly outer scopes as well) in the built in node.js debugger. So far I've managed to access the global scope using:

```
debug> repl
> global
```

but is there a function that lists local scope variables or a pointer to the local scope?
See the [debugger commands](http://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html) and [global object](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html) for more info.

Comment: That is your reason to use common node debugger instead of [node-inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector)?

Comment: I'm debugging protractor tests, if there is a way to do that with node-inspector I'd be happy to use that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a Javascript variable that represents local scope? Like global?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8183739/is-there-a-javascript-variable-that-represents-local-scope-like-global)

Comment: @RuslanIsmagilov this is specifically in a debugging context, the other question is more generic, but they're related indeed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

no, currently it's not implemented in built in cli debugger. If you really need it I encourage you to try and add support yourself - the code is in `/lib/_debugger.js` and command is ["scope"](https://code.google.com/p/v8/wiki/DebuggerProtocol#Request_scope). It's doable in less than 50 lines of code